# subprocess with pipes python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, pipe

I want to perfom a bash command to get my my default interface :

```
ip route list | grep default | awk '{print $5}'
```

I want this but in a python script so I tried :

```
    cmd = "ip route list | grep default | awk '{print $5}'"
    ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

but it gives me `b'wlan0\n'` as an answer instead of `wlan0`...What other solutions I have or where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: use `output.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: …and maybe `.strip()`

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: excellent thanks a lot the combination of decode & strip is perfect

Answer (score 0):

The type of getting `b'wlan0\n'` value is `bytes` so you need to decode it. Usually the `utf-8` is used for it.

The `str/bytes` type handling is a big difference between `Python2` and `Python3`. These sites contain more details about it:

- http://python3porting.com/problems.html#bytes-strings-and-unicode
- https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html

I have written a little example for the understanding:

**Code:**

```
bytes_var = b"wlan0"
string_var = "wlan0"
print("Type: {type}, Value: {val}".format(type=type(bytes_var),
                                          val=bytes_var))
print("Type: {type}, Value: {val}".format(type=type(string_var),
                                          val=string_var))
print("Type: {type}, Value: {val}".format(type=type(bytes_var.decode("utf-8")),
                                          val=bytes_var.decode("utf-8")))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Type: <class 'bytes'>, Value: b'wlan0'
Type: <class 'str'>, Value: wlan0
Type: <class 'str'>, Value: wlan0
```

Furthermore, of course you can remove the trailing white-spaces with the `x.strip()`.

So in your case you should use the following line:

```
print(output.decode("utf-8")).strip())
```